# ComboBox PHP PDO Class not populating at all but leaves blank place holders

Tags: php, pdo

I fixed the problem so I wanted to share the solution. Hopefully, this helps people that want to populate a combobox.

```
try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=Jamal-PC;dbname=japanesewords',$username,$password);
$sql ='SELECT id, Englishword FROM Japanesedefinition;';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


select name="Japanese" id="Japanese"> 
    <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Englishword']; ?></option> 
    <?php endforeach ?> 
    </select>
```

Comment: Also, I do not believe that you have enabled error reporting in your `php.ini` file as you would be seeing an error for the above code.

Comment: I enabled the errors like I was instructed to. I could of done this incorrectly.

Comment: In `php.ini`, find the line `error_reporting`, make sure it is uncommented (no `#` or `;` at the start of the line) and set its value to `E_ALL`. Similarly, find `display_errors` and set its value to `On`. There should only be one of each property. Then, restart your web server.

Comment: Can you **please**, **EDIT YOUR QUESTION WITH THE ACTUAL CODE YOU ARE USING**. Every time you edit your question, the code changes to yet another incompatible version.

Comment: I am a bit confused at this point. I really appreciate your help. I don't want to frustrate you. Is there a tutorial I could possibly learn from. I really want to get this combobox to work. At first, it seemed so simple in my mind.

Comment: Again, why have you *partially* adopted Rob's answer? Why did you remove the `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` fetch type from `fetchAll()`?

Comment: I also made the changes in the php.ini file. I think I got them all.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping `<option>` around `<option>`. You should also use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` since you are selecting a single field.

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

<select name="Japanese" id="Japanese">
<?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>
<option><?= $row; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

**Edit:** I see you changed your query to select 2 fields now instead of just one. Rather than fetching a column, you should use `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`. Example:

```
<?php $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR); ?>

<select name="Japanese" id="Japanese">
<?php foreach($data as $k => $v)
    printf('<option value="%d">%s</option>', $k, $v); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Fixed the errors mentioned, but still not able to get it to populate. It has the empty spaces, but can't get it to fill in.

Comment: To anyone having trouble this is the code that worked for me              dselect name="Japanese" id="Japanese"> 
<?php foreach($data as $row) : ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Englishword']; ?></option> 
<?php endforeach ?> 
</select>

Comment: You changed your query. My answer was based on you selecting a single field. Answer updated.

Comment: I don't understand why this post was marked down so negatively. I really new to programming with PHP. Not even a month, so I think I asked a legit question. From doing google searches, it looks like a lot of people have had this problem.